# How to get xhr object from $.load function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

A user click a button that makes a request and then click again and again and again...

I wanted to use `xhr.abort()`, but I don't know if I can retrieve it from [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it for an abort, you should perhaps use `$.get()` instead.

```
var xhr = $.get('url', function(response) {
    $('#myElement').append( response );
});

xhr.abort();
```